# Use println in a swift app

Tags: ios, swift, println

I am new to swift and iOS development and wanted to build a simple `Hello World` app but I don't know where to write the `println` or find any tutorials as all are using the `UIStoryboard`. Could you tell me how to output `hello world` without using `UIStoryboard` and which file to write it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where do you expect to write hello world to? The screen, the console?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/swift/resources/

Comment: If you run the helloworld app in the ios simulator, your println text will appear in the xcode-console. If you run it on a device, nothing will happen.

Comment: you need to use a UILabel to print it on the devices screen, you can make it in the storyboard or in your code

Comment: In another deleted question the OP asked: "how do you use a ui label to println a string in swift."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print the message in the **Xcode console** (you can do this in *any file*):

```
println("Hello World!)
```

If you want to see the message in the **simulator** (put this in your *view controller file*):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var helloWorldLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
    helloWorldLabel.text = "Hello World!"
    self.view.addSubview(helloWorldLabel)
}
```

As a beginner program, I found the **WWDC videos** very *helpful*, you might want to check them out.

***Hope this helps,*
Will**

Comment: Thanks you so much you're the best! It took me so long to work it out.

Answer (score -1):

In objective c we use the NSLog and in swift we use the println , to check the output in console . 
suppose in a method we want to check the conditional statement like if -else :

```
 if error != nil {
                println("Error: \(error)") //
            }
            else {
                println("Successfully")
                println("we can also use the break points to check the value")
```

}

Comment: This doesn't help him at all, he knows how to send an output in the console, he wants to know how to output it on the device e.g. using a UILabel.

Comment: @MichaelMooney Note that the OP did not mention or ask about using a `UILabel` in this question.